# Writing an OS agnostic file path

Tags: r, windows, macos

I've found myself working with some R files on both Windows and OSX.

In almost all of the R files I'm creating for this project, there is a need to import some data from the file system.

To do this in a way that works for both OS's (OSs?) I have something like this at the top of most files:

```
if (Sys.info()['sysname'] == 'Windows'){
    project_path <- "C:/Users/Bilbo/project_folder"
} else { 
    project_path <- "~/project_folder"
```

It'd be nice to not implement this separately in every file. One idea is to write a single function `get_folder_path()` that returns the appropriate path, but the problem is I'd have to import the file with that function with `source()` which requires me to ask for `Sys.info()['sysname']`, defeating the purpose.

It seems excessive to write a package with only this function (though I've never used `roxygen` and it might be a good exercise) so that I can just do `library(agnosticImporter)`.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: I think `fs` might help (though I've never used it) (in the `tidyverse`) - https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/01/fs-1.0.0/

Comment: Windows offers tilde expansion to the user home directory too. In any case, `Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")` or `Sys.getenv("HOME")` might be useful.

Comment: Are you looking for `?path.expand`? Try `path.expand(project_path)` and see if it's it.

Comment: @CPak It looks like `fs` is good for doing operations on file systems (cross-platform) like adding and deleting files.  But it doesn't seem to have at first glance a file path converter doohicky.

Comment: @James `"~/project_folder"` is not recognized as a valid path on my Windows machine, but Sys.getenv("HOME") does the trick.

Comment: @RuiBarradas that's the ticket.

Comment: Also if anyone cared about [the plural form of "OS"](http://technotes.whw1.com/computer-related/operating-systems/22-what-is-the-plural-of-os-operating-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have any luck with the comments, so I [wrote a tiny package](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) for this purpose.

The function `get_home_dir()` from [agnOStic](https://github.com/colorlace/agnOStic) returns "C:\\Users\\Bilbo\\" on Windows and "~/" on Mac or linux.